# onClick window.open Two Links in PHP not Working

Tags: javascript, php

Maybe someone can explain why this isn't working and how to fix it.  I'm using WP page navi to send someone to another link at the end of the paged post.  I want one link to go to another post and the other link to go to another website.

```
if ( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') )
{
    ob_start();
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'type' => 'multipart' ) );
    $pagenavi = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    if ( !strstr($pagenavi, 'nextpostslink') ) $pagenavi = str_replace('</div>', '<a href="http://website2.com" onClick="window.open(\'http://website1.com/another-post/\'); return true; style="float:right;" rel="next" class="nextpostslink">NEXT &gt;&gt;</a>'."\r".'</div>', $pagenavi);
    echo $pagenavi;
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing.  It only opens the first link but if I use it in just straight html it works fine minus the escapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you not closing the double quote,try to change,

```
onClick="window.open(\'http://website1.com/another-post/\');
```

to

```
onClick="window.open(\'http://website1.com/another-post/\');"
```

Comment: Ah man I knew it was something stupid like that.  I thought I had it after the return true; part of it but I obviously copied and pasted wrong, doh.  Thanks!